# Script to resolve GUID to String in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vbscript

I am trying to understand the output of the following VB script that resolves a GUID to a string in active directory:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B325649

This article demonstrates how to convert the hexadecimal string form of an object's GUID into its string form:

Paste the following code in a .vbs file.

```
'================================================================
'Set the next line to reflect a DN for an object in the directory
'================================================================
Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Username,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM")
MsgBox "The GUID string Value for user " & obj.Get("DisplayName") & _
       " is " &  ConvertHexStringGUIDToStringGUID(obj.GUID)

'================================================================
' ConvertHexStringGUIDToStringGUID function
'================================================================
Function ConvertHexStringGUIDToStringGUID(strOctet)
    Dim tmpGUID, GUIDStr
    'Convert the string by flipping the bits around.
    GUIDStr = Mid(strOctet, 7, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  5, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  3, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  1, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 11, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  9, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 15, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 13, 2)
    GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 17, Len(strOctet))

    tmpGUID = "{" & Mid(GUIDStr,  1,  8) & "-" & Mid(GUIDStr,  9, 4) & _
              "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 13,  4) & "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 17, 4) & _
              "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 21, 15) & "}"

    ConvertHexStringGUIDToStringGUID = tmpGUID
End Function
```

My question is:

- What is the output of this script?
- Do you have to have a domian account to run the command `Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Username,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your last question first: yes, you need a domain account, otherwise `GetObject()` will fail.

As for your first question: The `GUID` property returns a string of hexadecimal values, which are ordered according to the [GUID data structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373931%28VS.85%29.aspx). Since the first 4 bytes are stored as a DWORD followed by 2 WORDs you have to take the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) into account. intel machines store WORDs and DWORDs little endian encoded ([least significant byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_byte) first), so you have to reverse the byte order of the first 4 bytes. The rest of the data structure is a byte array, so those bytes are already in the correct order.

**Example:**

Let's say you have a hex string like this:

```
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
```

You would split it like this:

```
00010203 0405 0607 08090a0b0c0d0e0f
DWORD    WORD WORD BYTE[]
```

Because of the little endian encoding you have to reverse the order of the first 4 bytes (every 2-digit hex value representing 1 byte):

```
03020100 0504 0706 08090a0b0c0d0e0f
```

That's what this part of the code does (comments mine):

```
' reverse DWORD
GUIDStr = Mid(strOctet, 7, 2)
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  5, 2)
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  3, 2)
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  1, 2)
' reverse 1st WORD
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 11, 2)
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet,  9, 2)
' reverse 2nd WORD
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 15, 2)
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 13, 2)
```

The remainder of the string represents a byte array, so those bytes are used in order:

```
GUIDStr = GUIDStr + Mid(strOctet, 17, Len(strOctet))
```

The next instruction formats the hex string into a GUID string, grouping the digits properly (8-4-4-4-12):

```
tmpGUID = "{" & Mid(GUIDStr,  1,  8) & "-" & Mid(GUIDStr,  9, 4) & _
          "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 13,  4) & "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 17, 4) & _
          "-" & Mid(GUIDStr, 21, 15) & "}"
```

resulting in the following string:

```
{03020100-0504-0706-0809-0a0b0c0d0e0f}
```

Please see also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/05/25/141525.aspx) from Eric Lippert for a more thorough explanation.